# How can I make cell reference dynamic in IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, importrange

I am using a formula to import some values from a google sheet and concatenating them to make one value.

=CONCATENATE(IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Sheet1'!A2")," ",IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Sheet1'!B2")," ",IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Sheet1'!C2")," ",IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Sheet1'!D2"))

How can I make the cell references dynamic so that if I drag it down cell value changes to A3,B3,C3,D3?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to do a single importrange on a separate tab with the WHOLE range as the second parameter ("'Sheet1'!A2:D"). Then do a concatenation per row from that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IMPORTRANGE` formula is not a dynamic one and therefore does not allow modifying the ranges to it by dragging it down, as with other formulas.

However, a way to solve your issue is to do the `IMPORTRANGE` on another sheet, like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", "'Sheet1'!A1:D4")
```

Assuming that the data was imported into a `Import` sheet:

[image: imported data]

You can use the below formula on another sheet and drag it down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",FILTER(Import!$A1:$D1, Import!A1:D1<>"")))
```

After the above steps, this is how the end result will look like:

[image: data after concatenation]

#### Note

Also, please bear in mind that the above formulas were used considering the imported data was in the `A1:D4` range. You might need to adjust that to your case.

#### Reference

- [JOIN Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en);
- [FILTER Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en);
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).